# Error reporting when using Google Maps in the app:cxm: Can't load code for MapsDynamite.apk

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Google Maps is used for positioning in the APP, but when the map is opened, The interface becomes all white，it prompts "Googel Play services are updating".
This is my error log

```
E/ChimeraModuleLdr: Failed to load code for module FileApk(/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/MapsDynamite.apk)
    cxm: Can't load code for MapsDynamite.apk
        at cud.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):15)
        at cxl.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):70)
        at cxl.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):97)
        at cxl.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):93)
        at vze.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):34)
        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.loadModule(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):0)
        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.createModuleContextNoCrashUtils(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):7)
        at vyw.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):9)
        at cpm.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@202414035@20.24.14 (120306-319035315):11)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzj.zzb(Unknown Source:23)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzb(Unknown Source:170)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source:159)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load(Unknown Source:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zzc(Unknown Source:35)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zzb(Unknown Source:32)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzbz.zza(Unknown Source:14)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzd(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(Unknown Source:20)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source:21)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1384)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3744)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1065)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate(CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at com.lenzetech.antiloss.ui.MapGoogleFragment.onCreateView(MapGoogleFragment.java:293)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
2020-07-31 11:37:07.020 32249-32249/com.zoqin.trillo E/ChimeraModuleLdr:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Wrongly positioned：

```
 this.mView = paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.google_map_layout, paramViewGroup, false);
```

“build.gradle”Configured as：

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

"AndroidManifest.xml"Has been added in：

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```

I don’t know what caused the problem, if you have any ideas, you can discuss with me, thank you